# Show the convergents of these sequences?

Tags: analysis

Well guys I need some help. I need to find out if these sequences are 
convergent and if so I need to find the Limit of them:

Given is this formulae
 $\mid a_{n}-a\mid<\epsilon \ \forall n\geq N$

(1) $ a_{n}=(-1)^n n$

In my opinion it has to diverge as it oscilates between +n and -n and there is no N, so that the following members are in my epsilon.

(2) $b_{n}=(-1)^{n^2} $

Here i'm a bit confused to be honest it seems the same as (1)

(3) $ c_{n}=2^{n} $

Here i haven't found the trick yet. I only know it's the same as $\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ k\end{array}\right)$

Comment: $b_n$ oscillates too and $c_n$ increases.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$(1)$ $a_{2n}=2n \geq n$ so we have found a subsequence of $a_{n}$ which diverges to $\infty $. This means that the sequence is unbounded.

$(2)$ $b_{n}=((-1)^{n})^{n}$ so $b_{2n}=1$ while $b_{2n+1}=-1$

$(3)$ prove $n < 2^n$ by induction

Answer (score 0):

let $(3)$ be convergent,

$|c_n - a| \lt e$

$(c_n - a)^2 \lt e^2$

$2^{2n} + a^2 -2\times2^n\times a \lt e^2$

$2^{2n} + a^2 -2^{n+1}a \lt e^2$

let $x = 2^n$

$x^2 + a^2 - 2ax \lt e^2$

$x^2 - 2ax + (a^2 - e^2) \lt 0$

Since $a > 0$
thus there are infinitely many points for which the inequality is not satisfied. 
thus divergent.